# foreach ($list as $key => $categoryTournament) with $key unordered

Tags: php

I'm using Laravel, but I think this is general to PHP.

When I try to loop a Collection with with this code

```
@foreach($categoryTournaments as $key => $categoryTournament)
   {{ $key }} // Means echo
@endforeach
```

**Output:**  `1 0 2 4 3`

I randomly get unorderer keys, instead of having `0 1 2 3 4` as I should expect.

CategoryTournament is an Object, I join the 5 objects:

```
Collection {#522 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => CategoryTournament {#523 ▼
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "category_tournament"
      +timestamps: true
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 164
        "tournament_id" => 71
        "category_id" => 5
        "created_at" => "2016-03-23 00:04:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-03-23 00:04:47"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    1 => CategoryTournament {#524 ▼
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "category_tournament"
      +timestamps: true
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    2 => CategoryTournament {#525 ▼
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "category_tournament"
      +timestamps: true
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    3 => CategoryTournament {#526 ▼
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "category_tournament"
      +timestamps: true
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    4 => CategoryTournament {#527 ▼
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "category_tournament"
      +timestamps: true
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Could you say what exactly Collection class is? Maybe its implementation of iterator interface contains some custom logic.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `ksort` function to sort the Array According to key

```
ksort($categoryTournaments);
```

This function Arrange your array keys in Ascending order

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro add this function above the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

It is actually completely normal that list is unordered. In PHP it is allowed.

If you want to have ordered list, you should use one of the functions: `ksort($categoryTournaments)` if that is possible.

If not:`$categoryTournaments->sortBy('id')`, where id is key you want to sort by.
Check other functions inside documentation you provided.